# How to write a loop based on user input in C++?

Tags: c++, loops

How do I run a loop based on the user input?

Example:

I ask how many students does the user want to calculate the grade.

if the user enters 2 students, then I will ask the user to input grades for exams, homework, quiz etc...

After the program calculate the first student grade, how do I run the loop again for the second student?

I tried using a while loop but it just goes to infinite loop.

What I did was:

```
cout << "number of student you want to calculate grade for" << endl; 

cin >> student; 

while (student) { 
... 
... 
... 
... 
}
```

when I run this it goes to infinite loop.

Comment: [Here's a helpful link for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), that should help you write your program.

Answer (score -2):

you need to make sure you decrement student inside the loop as you check if there are any students left to get information for.

```
while(student > 0){ // check if any students left
    // your code to get student information
    student -= 1; // decrement students
}
```